# Why use MPI_Init() when code in front is parallel too?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I encountered a question about the use of `MPI_Init()`.

I want to initialize random number `randv` only on the root processor with the code in the context below. To see if my goal is fulfilled, I have the program print out the array `randv` by placing a do loop immediately after the line `call RANDOM_NUMBER(randv)`.

However, what is shown on the outcome screen is the repetition of the random number array by 8 times (given the number of processors is 8). My question is why the processors other than the root one are initialized before call `MPI_Init()`. If all the processors are awaken and have the same random number array before evoking `MPI_Init`, why bother to place call `MPI_Init()` for initialization?

Here is the example I use:

```
program main
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer :: i
  integer :: ierr
  integer :: irank
  integer :: nrow, ncol
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: randv
  nrow = 4
  ncol = 2
  allocate(randv(nrow,ncol))   
  call RANDOM_SEED
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(randv)
  do i = 1, nrow
    write(*,'(2(f5.2,x))') randv(i,:)    
  enddo   
  call MPI_Init ( ierr )
  allocate(row_list(ncol), col_list(nrow))  
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, irank, ierr )
  if( irank == 0 )then
    do i = 1, nrow
      write(*,'(2(f5.2,x))') randv(i,:)    
    enddo          
  endif
  call MPI_Finalize ( ierr ) 
  deallocate( randv )
end program
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how MPI works. The program you wrote is executed *by every process*. `MPI_Init` initializes the MPI environment s.t. those processes can interact. After initialization every process is uniquely identified by its *rank*. You have to make sure that, based on these ranks, each process works on different portions of your data, or performs different tasks.

Typically, you should run `MPI_Init` before anything else in your program.

Using `MPI_Comm_rank` you can obtain the ID of the current process (its *rank*). The first process always has the rank `0`. Therefore, if you want to run parts of the code on the "master" process only, you can test for `irank == 0`:

```
program main
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer :: i
  integer :: ierr
  integer :: irank
  integer :: nrow, ncol
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: randv

  ! Initialize MPI
  call MPI_Init ( ierr )
  ! Get process ID
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, irank, ierr )

  ! Executed on all processes
  nrow = 4
  ncol = 2
  allocate(randv(nrow,ncol))   

  ! Only exectued on the master process
  if ( irank == 0 ) then
    call RANDOM_SEED
    call RANDOM_NUMBER(randv)
    do i = 1, nrow
      write(*,'(2(f5.2,x))') randv(i,:)    
    enddo   
  endif

  ! Executed on all threads
  allocate(row_list(ncol), col_list(nrow))  

  ! Only exectued on the master process
  if ( irank == 0 ) then
    do i = 1, nrow
      write(*,'(2(f5.2,x))') randv(i,:)    
    enddo          
  endif

  deallocate( randv )

  ! Finalize MPI, should always be executed last
  call MPI_Finalize ( ierr ) 
end program
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "root process" in MPI outside of the context of collective operations.

Comment: @HristoIliev You're right. But you could interpret the first process as being kind of a root, or master, process. From what I've seen so far, process 0 is typically chosen for "administrative" tasks such as I/O (when using serial I/O). But I'll change that in the answer to be precise!

Comment: @HristoIliev According to this thread https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2014-05/msg00056.html some MPI implementations treat rank 0 differently than the other ones.

Comment: @VladimirF, that is implementation-specific behaviour and it is not defined the MPI standard. The only use of "root" in the standard is to designate the data sender/receiver for collective operations.

Comment: @HristoIliev is right - The MPI processes are peers, created together at time of mpirun.  Talk of root or master processes can lead to too much confusion, esp. since many MPI users are familiar with OpenMP, where there really is a master thread.